# Magento Payflow pro does not send INVNUM in Request to paypal

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7, payflowpro

I have magento site in 1.7.2 version and setup the paypal payment(Paypal Payflow Pro).

the transaction with paypal is done successfully but **Invoiced Id** not sent to paypal and In transaction i can not see INVNUM.

i know that when we make request to paypal we need to pass **"INVNUM"** but my site is not sending **INVNUM** to paypal in request, i captured the one transaction by doing debug mode enable.

any one have idea where i need to checked and fixed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In have upgrade version of magento 1.7.2 to latest version so ,in latest version of magenot it's working.